# BinaryFormatter serialization very different times for different classes

Tags: c#, tcp, binaryformatter

I am using `BinaryFormatter` to send different message types via TCP.

I use the following code to transmit a `MessageBase` derived class:

```
private void TransmittingThread()
{
    log.Debug("TCPCommunicationLayer - TransmittingThread Startting");

    while (IsRunning)
    {
        try
        {
            // This blocks until a message is available
            MessageBase msg = MessageQueue.Take();

            if (msg != null)
            {
                Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopWatch.Start();

                BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                f.Serialize(ms, msg);

                long msgSize = ms.Length;
                log.Debug($"Transmitting - {msg.Report(true)} - {msgSize} Bytes - {stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
                f.Serialize(_client.GetStream(), msg);
                stopWatch.Stop();

                log.Debug($"Transmitted - {msg.Report(true)} - {stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
                ms.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error(e);
            Disconnect();
        }
    }

    while (MessageQueue.TryTake(out _)) { }

    log.Debug("TCPCommunicationLayer - TransmittingThread Exiting");
}
```

`MessageBase` is defined as:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class MessageBase
{
    protected MessageBase(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid Guid { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ParameterMessage<T> : MessageBase
{
    public ParameterMessage(string name, T data)
        : base(name)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public T Data { get; }
}
```

The following class which is about 5 Mb in size takes about 500 ms to transmit:

```
[Serializable]
public class SharedPreview : SharedPreviewParameters
{
    private byte[] _previewImageBuffer = Array.Empty<byte>();
    private byte[] _labelImageBuffer = Array.Empty<byte>();

    public SharedPreview(ScanInfo scanInfo, List<RegionOfInterest> regionsOfInterest, List<PredictiveFocusPoint> predictiveFocusPoints)
        : base(scanInfo, regionsOfInterest, predictiveFocusPoints)
    {
    }

    private byte[] EncodeImage(BitmapImage image)
    {
        // ...
    }

    private BitmapImage ExtractImage(byte[] buffer)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But the following class which is only 200 Kb takes about 20 seconds:

```
[Serializable]
public class ClientLogDefinition
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string FullPath { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class SharedClientLogs
{
    public List<ClientLogDefinition> ClientLogs { get; } = new List<ClientLogDefinition>();
}
```

I realize I could convert the strings to byte arrays which might solve the issue but I would really like to know what is causing the very slow performance with large strings

Comment: Serialization is slow.  It uses reflection.  What is the size of the data and what is you network speed?  Some of the slowness may be the serialization and some may be the network speed.  Calculate the size of the data to get a better estimate of how much of the time is the serialization and how much is the data transfer to be sure what is causing the slowness.

Comment: I mentioned in the original text that:
The message containing the SharedPreview was about 5Mb and took about 500ms.
The message containing the SharedClientLogs was about 200Kb but took about 20s.
The class containing strings took far longer even though it had far less data.

Comment: I would really recommend against using binaryFormatter. It is slow, fragile and insecure. It is so bad that it has been obsoleted in newer .Net versions. There are plenty of good alternatives, json and Profobuf  (.net) are my favorites. But just about everything is better than binary formatter. The only valid use case in my opinion is legacy code.

Comment: I would also consider using a higher level protocol instead of TCP. TCP require you to handle message framing and several other things yourself, and I see little evidence of that in your code. A protocol that handles actual messages, like MQTT, is probably much easier to use.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.
I have modified my SharedClientLogs class to contain byte[] rather than string and I have also modified my TransmittingThread code to write the MemoryStream and so am only using BinaryFormatter to create the byte[]. (Not updated code here though)
But neither of the responses have actually answered my question.
The security issue is not a problem in my case as this is only going to be used across a local private network.

Comment: [Microsoft recommend against the use of binary formatter due to security issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide). It literally only still exists because of backwards compatibility.

Comment: 5MB / 500ms = 10MB/Sec x 10 bits/ Byte = 100Mb/sec which good.  200KB/20s = 10Kb/Sec x 10bits/Byte = 100Kb which is slow.  It is on the same link which may indicate a virus checker (or firewall) is check the text file but not a binary file.  Try GZIP (compression) and see what happens.

Comment: Why are you serializing twice and measuring the combined time of that? Copy from `ms` to `_client.GetStream()`.

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is not just obsolete but tends to produce huge payloads especially when generic types are serialized. As an alternative, you can try [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#binary-serialization) serializer (disclaimer: written by me), which is safer, and produces much more [compact](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nQfFrQ) results. But please note that if in your case the biggest data is the encoded image as `byte[]`, then the result will not be that much smaller.